# Understanding $\mathbb{R}^3/N$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I'm considering the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I'm trying to understand the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^3/N$ where 
$$N=\{a(1,1,1)|a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Since $N$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, in an analogy to group theory, this would sort of be my $zero$ or my identity object in the quotient space.  And from what I gather, is the quotient space would be the space of all lines parallel to my line $a(1,1,1)$?  Is this completely off?

Comment: It's exactly that: The space of all parallel lines to $\{(t,t,t), t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Each element of the quotient has the form $(x,y,z)+\{a(1,1,1)/ a\in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(x,y,z)+a(1,1,1)/ a\in \mathbb{R}\}$, this is the line that crosses trough the point $(x,y,z)$ and has director vector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Yes. You are right on the mark.

Comment: So this particular subspace $N$ is 1-dimensional.  Now, then what is the dimension of the quotient space?  Is it 3 dimensional? (would make sense)

Comment: It's 2-dimensional: A basis for this space is (for example) $\{(1,0,0)+N, (0,1,0)+N\}$.  You can identify each line of that kind with it's intersection with the $XY$ plane, I think (I'm not sure) the quotient space would be isomorphic to subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ $XY$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I think I get it now.  I was driving and I actually visualized what you mentioned in your comment; that collapsing of each line to a point.  As a quick bit of understanding, basis for the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ could be {(1,0,0)+N,(0,1,0)+N,(1,1,1)+N}, which I think really shows why.  Thanks for your help.